# 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematical-modeling

I try to distribute beams on an horizontal array, with increasing spacings according to this series.

1+1=**2**  2+2=**4**  4+3=**7** 7+4=**11** 11+5=**16** 16+6=**22**

I'd like to feel what it looks like and learn how to change the "rate of growth" it has.

I tried to put: xn = n(n-1)/2 + 1 (found [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-finding-rule.html)) into [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) online graph builder.

Didn't work, welcome any help.
I'm also intersted in any kind of "slow growing function"

Comment: [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+7%2C+11%2C+16%2C+22&language=english&go=Search) is a search result on OEIS (just preliminary)

Comment: So, just to be clear, the series is $a_0 = 1$, $a_{n + 1} = a_n + n$, right?

Comment: Well, $n(n-1)/2+1$ should work, if the first term has $n=1$.

Comment: If the first term is $n=1$, then it is $n(n+1)/2 + 1$

Comment: No idea what you mean by "learn how to change the rate of growth it has."

Comment: "*learn how to change the 'rate of growth' it has*"  The function you describe grows at a quadratic rate and can be expressed in the form $an^2+bn+c$ (*specifically with $a=\frac{1}{2}$*).  If you want it to continue to be quadratic but grow slower, then just decrease the factor of $a$ or use a linear closed form instead, for example by instead of adding $n$ at each step, adding $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the sum of a general quadratic sequence is:

$$S_2(n,s,d_1,c) = \cfrac{n(cn^2 + 2c + 3nd_1 + 6s - 3cn - 3d_1)}{6}$$

*Where $n$ is the number of terms to be summed, $s$ is the starting term of the series, $d_1$ is the first difference (subtracting the first term from the second term) and $c$ is the constant difference between the differences.*

From your series $1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + \ ...$ we can see that $s = 1$, $d_1 = 1$, $c = 1$.

So you want the $n$th term here, which means we can calculate the sum up to and including $n$ terms then subtract the sum up to and including $n-1$ terms. Plugging in the values it gives us the $n$th term (denoted $T_n$):

$$T_n = S_2(n,1,1,1) - S_2(n-1,1,1,1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1$$

So it is correct, don't know why it didn't show it as correct for you though.